# subsystem request failed on channel 0 scp: Connection closed

Tags: ssh, gerrit, scp, subsystem

Running this command in the terminal:

```
scp -p -P 29418 michealvern.genzola@192.168.0.122:hooks/commit-msg "jyei-erp/.git/hooks/"
```

returns the following error:

> subsystem request failed on channel 0
>
> scp: Connection closed

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try **-O** as an option in your **scp** cmd, i.e.

**scp -p -O -P 29418 michealvern.genzola@192.168.0.122:hooks/commit-msg "jyei-erp/.git/hooks/"**

Faced similar issue. This solution is from comments in github regarding this problem. For more details - https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1945

Comment: Adding the `-O` worked for me, although our gerrit server doesn't include it in the clone command by default

Comment: This issue is more related to newer versions of macOS rather than Gerrit.

Comment: Well this issue only happened to me after I upgraded to: `OpenSSH_9.3p2, OpenSSL 3.1.3 19 Sep 2023`, from ssh7 + openssl 1.1 or something along those lines. I am using Ubuntu on WSL. As far as I understand, the change was made with SSH 8.8 so you had to start using the `-O` beyond that version.

Answer (score 33):

Got the exact symptom on Linux. Giving `-O` fixed the issue. From `scp manpage`

```bash
     -O      Use the original SCP protocol for file transfers instead of the SFTP protocol.  Forcing the use of the
             SCP protocol may be necessary for servers that do not implement SFTP, for backwards-compatibility for
             particular filename wildcard patterns and for expanding paths with a ‘~’ prefix for older SFTP servers.
```

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing this issue, adding -O flag fixed my issue as said by @pysbrg already above,
final command:

```
scp -p -O -P 29418 michealvern.genzola@192.168.0.122:hooks/commit-msg "jyei-erp/.git/hooks/"
```